# How to update list of elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, state

I'm having trouble updating a list of elements using React, when I run the code below and click on a 'star' element, react updates ALL the elements in this.state.stars instead of just the element at the given index:

```
class Ratings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let starArr = new Array(parseInt(this.props.numStars, 10)).fill({
      icon: "*",
      selected: false
    });
    this.state = {
      stars: starArr
    };
    this.selectStar = this.selectStar.bind(this);
  }

  selectStar(ind) {
    this.setState({
      stars: this.state.stars.map((star, index) => {
        if (index === ind) star.selected = !star.selected;
        return star;
      })
    });
  }

  makeStars() {
    return this.state.stars.map((star, ind) => (
      <span
        className={star.selected ? "star selected" : "star"}
        onClick={() => this.selectStar(ind)}
        key={ind}
      >
        {star.icon}
      </span>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="star-container">
        <span>{this.makeStars()}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Not sure why this is happening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in how you're instantiating your Array:

```
let starArr = new Array(parseInt(this.props.numStars, 10)).fill({
  icon: "*",
  selected: false
});
```

What that line is doing is filling each item in the array *with the same object*. Not objects all with the same values, but a reference to the same object. Then, since you're *mutating* that object in your click handler, each item in the Array changes because they're all a reference to that same object.

It's better to do a non-mutating update, like this:

```
this.setState({
  stars: this.state.stars.map((star, index) =>
    (index === ind)
      ? { ...star, selected: !star.selected }
      : star
  )
});
```

This will instead create a copy of the object at the Array index except with the `selected` property toggled.